Interpreting $\int_\gamma f = \int P\ \text{d}x + Q\ \text{d}y$ via differential forms?
I've often seen the expression $\def\g{\gamma}\def\dx{\text{d}x}\def\dy{\text{d}y}\def\td{\text{d}}\def\br{\textbf{r}}\def\dt{\text{d}t}\def\RR{\mathbb{R}}$
$$\int_\g f\ \td\br = \int P\ \dx+Q\ \dy$$
where $\g$ is a smooth map $[a,b]\to\RR^2$ and $f:\RR^2\to\RR^2$ has component functions $P$ and $Q$. Knowing that the LHS is defined as
$$\int_a^b f(\br(t))\cdot\br'(t)\ \dt,$$
does the equality hold when $\dx$ and $\dy$ are interepreted as differential forms?

Yes. See, for example, my YouTube lectures, particularly 3510 Day 29.

Yes, if $dx$ and $dy$ are interpreted as differential $1$-forms, then $P,dx + Q,dy$ is a differential $1$-form. The integral in the second display is essentially the definition of the integral of a $1$-form along a curve. The idea is that you parameterize the curve $\gamma$ (here, the parameterization is $\vec{r}(t)$) and then "pull back" the $1$-form using the parameterization to the interval $a \le t \le b$. I also suggest you watch @TedShifrin's video or look at his textbook to see the details
